# Norton SONAR blocks a signed wix bundle installer

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.8, norton

We are using Wix 3.8 with VS2013. We have a bundle installer, which runs couple of .MSI installers. One of .MSI installers contains multiple custom actions. For some reason, these custom actions are blocked by the Norton SONAR. Worse, these CAs are treated as threats, which doesn't reflect well on our company. I saw there was a similar issue on SO: [Alternatives to WiX Burn Bootstrapper? (Can the InstallShield LE bootstrapper be used?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431962/alternatives-to-wix-burn-bootstrapper-can-the-installshield-le-bootstrapper-be)

It has been two years since the issue was raised and "resolved", but we are still experiencing this same problem...

Our installer is signed. Strangely enough, when we ran the .MSI installers directly, Norton SONAR didn't block any of the CAs.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks in advance!